# Apache Reverse Proxy doesnt redirect from 80 to 443

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

This is my apache configuration. As far as I can tell, redirecting from 80 to 443 should be working, but it's not. I also tried the `Redirect` directive without quotes and deleting the `ProxyPass` & `ProxyPassReverse` from the 80 virtual host without avail.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver.com
        ServerAlias www.myserver.com

        ProxyPass / http://myserver.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://myserver.com:8080/
        Redirect "/" "https://myserver.com/"

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myserver.com
        ServerAlias www.myserver.com
        ProxyRequests Off

        RewriteEngine on
        # Rewrites websocket configuration
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^keep-alive,\ Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey.pem
        ProxyPass / http://myserver.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://myserver.com:8080/
        <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you try by removing trailing slashes and remove quotes (as you already did)?, also remove the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. Just keep `Redirect / https://www.myserver.com`

Comment: I removed everything but the redirect and ServerName + ServerAlias. Still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAlias www.myserver.com
    Redirect Permanent / https://myserver.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAlias www.myserver.com
    RewriteEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://myserver.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myserver.com:8080/

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myserver.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    SSLCertificateFile /path/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```